# Using sed to get the content of a file that is not between two lines

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have a file like:

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
#START#
no name 1
no name 2
#END#
name 4
```

And I'm looking for the opposite of `sed -n '/#START#/,/#END#/p'` to get as result:

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
```

What's the secret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed '/#START#/,/#END#/d'
```

Delete the lines within the range specified.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some `awk` solutions:

```
awk '/#START#/ {f=1} !f; /#END/ {f=0}' file
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
```

You can also using range, like the `sed`, but range is less flexible if you have more stuff to test:

```
awk '/#START#/,/#END/ {next} 1' file
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
```